# Converting time string to total seconds

Tags: python

I have some strings similar to the following:

```
"1h 43m"
"4d 21h"
"59m 55s"
```

How would I go about converting these times to the total seconds as an int/float?

For example:

```
"1h 43s" ----> 3643
"4d 21h" ---->  421200
"59m 55s" ----> 3595
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to parse the strings. Then you can easily calculate the total seconds from that.

Comment: if you were feeling especially malicious, you could swap all the `h` and `m` for their multiplication equivalent, space for addition, and `eval()` the result

Comment: The more complicated part is parsing the string. After that you can use builtin modules like `datetime` and use `timedelta` object with the `total_seconds` method.